# Init BeanPostProcessor at a later point

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing an external component for applications which contains functionality to inject Jersey Client filters into lazy-loaded clients.  Ive implemented a BeanPostProcessor that does this:

```java
public class ClientFilterInjector implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {


    private ClientTraceInterceptor clientTraceInterceptor;

    public ClientFilterInjector(ClientTraceInterceptor clientTraceInterceptor) {
        this.clientTraceInterceptor = clientTraceInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if(bean instanceof JerseyWebTarget) {
            ((JerseyWebTarget) bean).register(clientTraceInterceptor);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

However, Spring Boot apparently auto-scans for `BeanPostProcessor` implementations regardless of whether or not they're annotated or have a bean creation method.  Because of this, it screws up the order for which beans are created in the application.  Is there a way to defer the instantiation of a `BeanPostProcessor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you implement `BeanProcessor` in the form of an anonymous class it will not get auto-scanned in the Spring Boot application init and you can defer its instantiation whenever you want by adding it to the bean factory of the application context.

```java
((ConfigurableApplicationContext) appContext).getBeanFactory().addBeanPostProcessor(new BeanPostProcessor() {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean instanceof WebTarget) {
            ((WebTarget) bean).register(instance);
        }
        return bean;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add lazy annotation?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
```

By using this annotation it will effect on the first call but later on it will exactly the same.

```
public class ClientFilterInjector implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {


    private ClientTraceInterceptor clientTraceInterceptor;

    public ClientFilterInjector(ClientTraceInterceptor clientTraceInterceptor) {
        this.clientTraceInterceptor = clientTraceInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(@Lazy Object bean, String beanName) {
        if(bean instanceof JerseyWebTarget) {
            ((JerseyWebTarget) bean).register(clientTraceInterceptor);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but the main issue I'm having is with `BeanPostProcessor` being instantiated prematurely and screwing up bean creation and post-processing order.  I just want this available after application instantiation for when clients are being lazy-loaded.